# Visual Studio 2012 redirects bindings for Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a C#/.NET 4.0 project which is a DLL library that contains some custom activities for a TFS 2010 build workflow. The project compiles and everything works on our development boxes.

On our build server we recently installed Visual Studio 2012 and found out that our builds now fail with this error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll: Assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' uses 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

I have searched high and low and can not find how/why all the calls to Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll which resolve to v 10.0.0 on our DEV boxes now resolve to 11.0.0.0 on build server. There are no assembly binding redirects that I could find, no publisher policies, nothing!

ALl I need is to force MSBuild and the build process to refer to v 10.0.0 of all related DLLs on the build server and not to v 11.0.0.0. Any help would be much appreciated.

Please note this is not related to a "XAML workflow" problem but instead compiling a DLL project that happens to reference 10.0.0.0 of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete explanation is now available on my blog post [here](http://www.nikgupta.net/2013/06/compiling-custom-tfs-activities/)

The proper way to resolve this was to ensure that MSBuild pipeline would always reliably reference the correct version of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.* dlls. After a considerable amount of investigating the solution turned out to set the SpecificVersion flag true in the .csproj file for the assemblies we wanted forced resolution to a specific version.

Answer (score 1):

Open the .csproj for your custom activity library in notepad.  Update the TFS assembly references removing the version-specific metadata.

Even if you set the "Specific Version" property to False, it still may have the version-specific metadata attached to the reference:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>$(Dependencies)\TeamFoundationClient\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Removing the metadata should get that project building correctly.

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>$(Dependencies)\TeamFoundationClient\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. However that wouldn't work and for so many reasons. Suffice it to say that in the absence of a version specific information MSbuild would automatically always resolve to the latest version of a binary (especially so if it is strong named, which it is). I have managed to resolve this problem (in the last 20 minutes!) and would post an answer (detailed) tomorrow at some point.

Comment: @Nikhil, I had the exact same problem and removing the metadata was the solution.  Did you try removing the metadata, or is your conclusion that it wouldn't work for 'many reasons' just an assumption on your part?

Comment: Nick I tried. Honestly. It didn't work. And as a sort of an SME on MSBuild and how .NET resolves assembly references I kind of understand most of the reasons why it "shouldn't work". However when it comes to these situations we have to bear in mind that they are very very environment specific. As I said I did a lot of research into this yesterday and came up with a sure shot solution. I will post it soon here.

Comment: I'm in an environment with people using VS 2010, 2012, and 2013.  I don't care what version of the Microsoft.TeamFoundation I'm accessing, and this resolved my issue.  Thanks!